# QGIS WKT Raster Plugin error, what does this mean?

Tags: postgis, raster, qgis, postgresql

I have been playing with the WKT Raster plugin. I have installed the WKT Raster experimental binaries in PostGIS successfully and followed the instructions in the read me to the letter.

When i am in QGIS I use the WKT Raster plugin to "Load Raster to PostGIS" everything seems to run fine there but once completed I get this error below.

[image: Error message I receive after loading raster to postGIS]

Even though I get this error the table shows up in PostgreSQL and I can load it into QGIS but it does appear empty/blank. I checked in PostgreSQL and the table is there and it has values in it. Also the error message says "DbError: relation '' already exists", but its the first time I have ever created a table with that name in the DB.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ando

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe it would work with trunk instead of 1.6 release? Otherwise, your best bet is to contact the plugin author directly.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I did try the plugin with trunk as well but unfortunately I get the same error and results.

Comment: The error message tells you that the table already exists. Could you retry deleting the old table before? The plugin is not able to drop tables (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a WKTRaster developer (now is called PostGIS Raster). I strongly recommend you to use the last PostGIS Raster version, integrated in PostGIS. And the last GDAL version (1.8.0). The GDAL driver (used for communication with QGIS) in GDAL versions previous to 1.8.0 was buggy and unstable.

Further information in my blog: http://gis4free.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/how-to-install-and-configure-postgis-raster-on-windows/