# Loading a raster using QGIS into a PostGIS2.0 enabled database

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

Following on from my [attempt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17576/how-to-run-two-postgis-versions-in-parallel-on-windows/17955#17955) to install a postgresql 9.1 db with postgis 2.0 on windows 7, I am trying to figure out how to load a raster. I have successfully loaded a shapefile, and am trying to do the same with a `.tif` file using the `Load Raster to PostGIS` plugin (version 0.5.1) in QGIS (version 1.7). I have set up the connection to my db, and am using the following settings:

[image]

When I click on the `OK` button, I get the below error message. I've tried this with a `.adf` file and also a `.tif` file, both projected in Albert Equal Area Conic with an SRID of 102003.

```
Checking parameters...
Connecting to database...
Storing overview 1 on database...
Failed.
Finished storing overview 1.
Storing overview 2 on database...
Failed.
Finished storing overview 2.
Storing overview 3 on database...
Failed.
Finished storing overview 3.
Finished.
```

This process has not inserted anything into my database, and I don't understand the error message. Some previous related questions are [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16515/how-to-import-a-raster-into-postgis) (asked by me, using a different process on loading rasters) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7612/qgis-wkt-raster-plugin-error-what-does-this-mean) (using the same plugin but much earlier in the year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

celenius,

It's quite possible that the QGIS raster loader hasn't been revised yet to fit with the new changes we have in place.  I suggest trying the raster2pgsql.exe packaged with the latest windows experimental.  It should load tifs just fine.

Instructions here.

http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Loading_Rasters

Comment: When I try loading running the program from the command line using this `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin>raster2pgsql.exe -s 102003 -c -C F:\pop.tif > test.sql` I get an `Access is denied.` message (not certain if I have to provide a schema or not). Is there a way I can run it as an administrator? When I right-click and choose the `run as administrator` option the screen just pops and disappears - I can't pass it any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This command from [Boundless](https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/suite/4.7/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/raster2pgsql.html). Has worked for me

`raster2pgsql -I -C -s <SRID> <PATH> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE> | psql -d <DATABASE>`

Where

`<SRID> Spatial reference identifier e.g 4326 for WGS84 CRS`

`<PATH> Full path to the raster file (such as C:\MyData\land\landuse.tif)`

`<SCHEMA> Target schema where the new raster table will be created e.g public`

`<DBTABLE> New database table to be created (usually the same name as the source raster file)`

`<DATABASE> Target database where the table will be created`

The -I option will create a spatial GiST index on the raster column after the table is created. This is strongly recommended for improved performance. The -C option will apply the raster constraints (SRID, pixel size and so on) to ensure the new raster table is correctly registered in the raster_columns view.